# wp_enqueue_script adds only the first script

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

```
function banana_scripts() {     
    wp_enqueue_script('grid', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', null, null);
    wp_enqueue_script('grid', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', null, null);
}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'banana_scripts');
```

I have the above hook in my functions.php. The first js file gets included, the second not. Is it incorrect to call this function twice or more?

Comment: Any feedback on your previous issue with sticky posts. :-)

Comment: @Thank, I have seen your code, but I am not yet as far as to implement it immediately, I am cleaning up what I have so far, and need to fix some basic issues like scripts and styles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You gave each each script the same handle/id of 'grid'

Try something like this.

```
function banana_scripts() {     
    wp_enqueue_script('grid-jq', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.min.js', null,   null);
    wp_enqueue_script('grid-main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', null, null);
}   
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'banana_scripts');
```

Comment: Thanks, apparently it's not a good idea to copy-paste things, the 'handle' of the script is something I have skipped to change, I see what caused the conflict now. I have decided anyway to link jquery from an external source, but many thanks for this solution.

Comment: make sure when you link to an external resource to exclude the protocol. This will help conflicts if your site is http or https. example: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js');`